# My question got posted twice - bug?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

I posted a question on SO, and somehow two posts were created.

The question ids are consecutive, [77669138](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77669138) and [77669139](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77669139).

Within the HTML of both pages is the same dateCreated value `2023-12-15 22:38:03Z` .

This seems like a bug to me.